# inconsistency in getting WifiP2pInfo in WiFiDirect

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

i am creating an application based on `WifiDirect` in android but the issue that i am facing inconsistency in getting wifi p2p connection info.

i am checking whether wifi direct is on or not , it shows its true but still sometimes i am getting connection info and sometimes not and thats the reason why i am not getting `groupOwnerAddress`.

one more thing is that i get `networkInfo.isConnected()` to `false` and that time only i am not able to get the `WifiP2pInfo`. sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't pretty frustratio

```
wifiManager.requestConnectionInfo(wifiChannel, new ConnectionInfoListener(){

            @Override
            public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) {

             }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not understand your question entirely, could you post a step-wise instructions to reproduce your problem?

I found this website very useful: http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

Be sure to check `info.groupFormed` is `true`, before using `info.isGroupOwner` and `info.groupOwnerAddress`

`onConnectionInfo` may be called at any time, but only when `info.groupFormed` is `true` it contains useful information.

Hope this helps :)